# How do I install the OWASP ZAP certificate as a trusted system CA on Bluestacks?

Tags: certificates, bluestacks

I have a rooted Bluestacks Android. I would like to use ZAP to monitor its SSL traffic.

I exported ZAP's SSL certificate as a .cer file

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Now I wish to import this certificate into Bluestacks.

The way I found was using an APK called "Root Certificate Manager". However, when I try to import the .cer file, I get an error response saying the ".cer" extension isn't supported.

I guess I need to convert it but I can't find the right format to convert to.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found the solution and it's a little dumb/a little funny. It seems that "Root Certificate Manager" is able to import the same .cer file if it is placed in the device's storage. I guess they have a bug in their "import from Windows" functionality.